# Web API 2 - returning JSON, a property that is false is not included

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

The JSON returned when a REST request is made all works great except any bool property, if false, does not get included in the JSON (verified via Fiddler). I tried:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public bool success { get; set; }
```

but it still didn't return it.

Any suggestions? And I do like that it doesn't return anything for nulls, it's just bools that I want always returned.

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    }
}
```

DatasourceController.cs:

```
public class DatasourceController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet("datasource/metadata/{datasource}")]
    public MetaDataInfo GetDatasourceSchema(string datasource, string node = "")
    {
        DocumentInfo docInfo = DocumentData.GetDocInfo("dave");
        return MetaDataFactory.GetMetaDataInfo(docInfo, datasource, node);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your HttpConfiguration and the whole controller/model ?

Comment: Updated as requested - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same information.
It turns out you [can specify for a specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973056/json-net-defaultvaluehandling-exempting-boolean-alone) property using:

```
[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]
```

I've tested on ASP.NET Core 1 RC2.
That's MVC 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by putting the `[DefaultValue(false)]` attribute above your `success` variable and other bool variables you should get your desired result.

You have set `DefaultValueHandling` to `Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate`.  From the documentation we can read:

> Ignore members where the member value is the same as the member's default value when serializing objects and sets members to their default value when deserializing.

As I read that it means that during  serializing your false boolean values should disappear.  However, as long as it has a default value it will appear in the JSON again when you deserialize.

Comment: I tried it (pretty sure I tried it before) and no luck. That IgnoreAndPopulate appears to override everything. I've switched it to Include which does pass back a bit more than I would like, but not a ton.