# Json.net DefaultValueHandling exempting boolean alone

Tags: c#, json.net

While serializing using json.net i used DefaultValueHandling.Ignore in serialization settings,  which result in removal of key if the bool is set false. I want that to be exempted for type bool alone, and apply for other types and classes. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` in serialization settings can be overridden by decorating any property with `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]` attribute. Here is the class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]
    public bool IsEmployed { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say that we have the following sample:

```
var person = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                IsEmployed = false
            };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Will result in following json:

```
{
    "FirstName": "John",
    "IsEmployed": false
}
```