# JSON serializer - when boolean value set to false key is missing on frontend

Tags: c#, json, typescript, asp.net-core

I have a webapi (ASP.Net Core) + frontend app (Angular). I'm passing some data that are stored in a json file on disk from the backend to frontend. On the frontend, for boolean properties, I'm missing them if the value was set to false. Using Newtonsoft.JSON.

Let say I have the following class:

```
public class Element<T>
{
    public Element(T value, T defaultValue, string name)
    {
        Value = value;
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        TypeName = name
    }
public T Value { get; set; }
public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
public string TypeName { get; set;}
}
```

Object creation:

```
public class Setting
{
    public Element<bool> SomeBoolObject { get; set; } = new Element<bool>(false, false, "boolean");
}
```

JSON file on disk:

```
"SomeBoolObject": {
"value": false,
"defaultvalue": false,
"typename": "boolean"
}
```

And then on frontend I have only

```
{
    "SomeBoolObject": {
    "typeName": "Boolean"
    }
}
```

The Value and DefaultValue keys are missing from the object, but only when value is set to false. When I set it to true then on frontend I got all keys and values:

```
"SomeBoolObject": {
"value": true,
"defaultvalue": true,
"typename": "boolean"
}
```

And on frontend:

```
{
    "SomeBoolObject": {
    "value": 1,
    "defaultValue": 1,  
    "typeName": "Boolean"
    }
}
```

What could be the reason of such behavior? Do I need to write some custom serializer for handling "false" values?

This is kind of similar to [Json.net DefaultValueHandling exempting boolean alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973056/json-net-defaultvaluehandling-exempting-boolean-alone)

But the proposed solution did not work for me.

Comment: What serializer are you using? JSON.Net? Or maybe ASP.Net Json Serializer?

Comment: Forgot to add - Newtonsoft.JSON

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

```
var serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (SomeBoolObject, new JsonSerializerSettings {
  DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include
});
```

[LIVE DEMO LINK](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kNfr29)

Comment: Tried this but with no luck. Adding [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)] for properties I was missing fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tackle the issue with adding some attributes for properties:

```
public class Element<T>
{
    public Element(T value, T defaultValue, string name)
    {
        Value = value;
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        TypeName = name
    }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public T Value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Mention the .NET/.NET Core Framework and Newtonsoft.Json versions in question. so that others might get some idea of what caused the issue.